# How do I split on multiple conditions?

Tags: ruby, string, split

With Ruby how do I split on either one of tow conditions -- wheter there are 3 or more spaces or a tab charadter?  I tried this

```
2.4.0 :003 > line = "a\tb\tc"
 => "a\tb\tc"
2.4.0 :004 > line.split(/([[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]]+|\t)/)
 => ["a", "\t", "b", "\t", "c"]
```

but as you can see, the tab character itself is getting included in my results.  The results should be

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: JFYI, tab character _is_ whitespace and is matched by `[:space:]` character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just `split`?

```
p "a\tb\tc".split
# ["a", "b", "c"]
p "a\tb\tc\t\tc\t\t\t\t\t\t\tc\ts\ts\tt".split
# ["a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "s", "s", "t"]
```

Although that doesn't split when there are three 3 or more white spaces, this might work:

```
p "a\tb\tc\t\tc\t\t\   t\t\tc\ts\ts\tt".split(/\s{3,}|\t/)
# => ["a", "b", "c", "c", "t", "c", "s", "s", "t"]
```

Comment: THat doesn't work, though.  If my line is "aa bb     cc", split returns  ["aa", "bb", "cc"], but since I only want to split on 3 or more spaces or a tab, the example should yield ["aa bb", "cc"]

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Now it’s plain wrong: `/\t*/` matcher matches everything, try the string with two letters e.g. `"abc"`.

Comment: So `/\s{3,}+|\t+/`? @mudasobwa

Comment: `\p{Space}{3,}|\t+` is safer for different omniguruma versions.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa, I didn't know it.

Comment: `"a\tb\nc".split #=> ["a", "b", "c"]`, but the OP did not say to split on newlines. True, the choice of the name `line` for a variable may suggest the string contains no newlines, but I think it's better to split on spaces and tabs only, and not on newlines (and carriage returns and form feeds).

Answer (score 1):

```
line = "aa bb    cc\tdd"
line.split /\p{Space}{3,}|\t+/
#⇒ ["aa bb", "cc", "dd"]
```